# How to create a Waterfall plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d, matplotlib-3d

Is there a python module that will do a waterfall plot like MATLAB does? I googled 'numpy waterfall', 'scipy waterfall', and 'matplotlib waterfall', but did not find anything.

Comment: I think this might also be known as a 'ridgeline plot'. There are quite a few blog posts on this, e.g. [this one in mpl](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/create-ridgeplots-in-matplotlib/) and [this one in plotly](https://ridgeplot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [mplot3d](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#wireframe-plots):

```
# copied from 
# http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_examples/mplot3d/wire3d_demo.py

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=10)

plt.show()
```

[image: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#wireframe-plots]

I don't know how to get results as nice as Matlab does.

---

If you want more, you may also have a look at [MayaVi](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html#how-is-mplot3d-different-from-mayavi): http://mayavi.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 22):

You can do a waterfall in matplotlib using the [PolyCollection](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html?highlight=polycollection#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection) class. See this specific [example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/polys3d_demo.html) to have more details on how to do a waterfall using this class.

Also, you might find this [blog post](http://austringer.net/wp/index.php/2011/05/20/plotting-a-dolphin-biosonar-click-train/) useful, since the author shows that you might obtain some 'visual bug' in some specific situation (depending on the view angle chosen).

Below is an example of a waterfall made with matplotlib (image from the blog post):
[image]
<sub>(source: [austringer.net](http://austringer.net/images/biosonar/wfall_demo.png))</sub>

Answer (score 4):

The Wikipedia type of [Waterfall chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_chart) one can obtain also like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def waterfall(series):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'pos':np.maximum(series,0),'neg':np.minimum(series,0)})
    blank = series.cumsum().shift(1).fillna(0)
    df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, bottom=blank, color=['r','b'])
    step = blank.reset_index(drop=True).repeat(3).shift(-1)
    step[1::3] = np.nan
    plt.plot(step.index, step.values,'k')

test = pd.Series(-1 + 2 * np.random.rand(10), index=list('abcdefghij'))
waterfall(test)
```

Comment: Chris Moffitt made a nice post with some more explanation (he was clearly inspired by above code :-) ): see http://pbpython.com/waterfall-chart.html

Comment: Nice example, but please compare [Waterfall plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_plot) to [Waterfall chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_chart). The former is of interest here, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

I have generated a function that replicates the matlab waterfall behaviour in matplotlib. That is:

1. It generates the 3D shape as many independent and parallel 2D curves
2. Its color comes from a colormap in the z values

I started from two examples in matplotlib documentation: [multicolor lines](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html) and [multiple lines in 3d plot](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/polys3d_demo.html). From these examples, I only saw possible to draw lines whose color varies following a given colormap according to its z value following the example, which is reshaping the input array to draw the line by segments of 2 points and setting the color of the segment to the z mean value between these 2 points.

Thus, given the input matrixes `n,m` matrixes `X`,`Y` and `Z`, the function loops over the smallest dimension between `n,m` to plot each of the waterfall plot independent lines as a line collection of the 2 points segments as explained above.

```
def waterfall_plot(fig,ax,X,Y,Z,**kwargs):
    '''
    Make a waterfall plot
    Input:
        fig,ax : matplotlib figure and axes to populate
        Z : n,m numpy array. Must be a 2d array even if only one line should be plotted
        X,Y : n,m array
        kwargs : kwargs are directly passed to the LineCollection object
    '''
    # Set normalization to the same values for all plots
    norm = plt.Normalize(Z.min().min(), Z.max().max())
    # Check sizes to loop always over the smallest dimension
    n,m = Z.shape
    if n>m:
        X=X.T; Y=Y.T; Z=Z.T
        m,n = n,m

    for j in range(n):
        # reshape the X,Z into pairs 
        points = np.array([X[j,:], Z[j,:]]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
        segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)  
        # The values used by the colormap are the input to the array parameter
        lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap='plasma', norm=norm, array=(Z[j,1:]+Z[j,:-1])/2, **kwargs)
        line = ax.add_collection3d(lc,zs=(Y[j,1:]+Y[j,:-1])/2, zdir='y') # add line to axes

    fig.colorbar(lc) # add colorbar, as the normalization is the same for all
    # it doesent matter which of the lc objects we use
    ax.auto_scale_xyz(X,Y,Z) # set axis limits
```

Therefore, plots looking like matlab waterfall can be easily generated with the same input matrixes as a matplotlib surface plot:

```
import numpy as np; import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Generate data
x = np.linspace(-2,2, 500)
y = np.linspace(-2,2, 60)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = np.sin(X**2+Y**2)-.2*X
# Generate waterfall plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
waterfall_plot(fig,ax,X,Y,Z,linewidth=1.5,alpha=0.5) 
ax.set_xlabel('X'); ax.set_ylabel('Y'); ax.set_zlabel('Z') 
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image: default waterfall]

The function assumes that when generating the meshgrid, the `x` array is the longest, and by default the lines have fixed y, and its the x coordinate what varies. However, if the size of the `y` array is longer, the matrixes are transposed, generating the lines with fixed x. Thus, generating the meshgrid with the sizes inverted (`len(x)=60` and `len(y)=500`) yields:

[image: non default waterfall]

To see what are the possibilities of the `**kwargs` argument, refer to the [LineCollection class documantation](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection) and to its [`set_` methods](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection.set).