# 3D Waterfall Plot with Colored Heights

Tags: python, matplotlib, surface, matplotlib-3d, matplotlib.mlab

I'm trying to visualise a dataset in 3D which consists of a time series (along y) of x-z data, using Python and Matplotlib.

I'd like to create a plot like the one below (which was made in Python: http://austringer.net/wp/index.php/2011/05/20/plotting-a-dolphin-biosonar-click-train/), but where the colour varies with Z - i.e. so the intensity is shown by a colormap as well as the peak height, for clarity.

[image]

An example showing the colormap in Z is (apparently made using MATLAB):
[image]

This effect can be created using the waterfall plot option in MATLAB, but I understand there is no direct equivalent of this in Python.

I have also tried using the plot_surface option in Python (below), which works ok, but I'd like to 'force' the lines running over the surface to only be in the x direction (i.e. making it look more like a stacked time series than a surface). Is this possible?
[image]

Any help or advice greatly welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: How tied are you to matplotlib specifically? I think you'll be at the edge of its current capability. If mayavi is acceptable, [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287861/creating-intersecting-images-in-matplotlib-with-imshow-or-other-function/25295272#25295272) might help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Waterfall plot python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209646/waterfall-plot-python)

Answer (score 5):

I have generated a function that replicates the matlab waterfall behaviour in matplotlib, but I don't think it is the best solution when it comes to performance.

I started from two examples in matplotlib documentation: [multicolor lines](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html) and [multiple lines in 3d plot](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/polys3d_demo.html). From these examples, I only saw possible to draw lines whose color varies following a given colormap according to its z value following the example, which is reshaping the input array to draw the line by segments of 2 points and setting the color of the segment to the z mean value between the 2 points.

Thus, given the input matrixes `n,m` matrixes `X`,`Y` and `Z`, the function loops over the smallest dimension between `n,m` to plot each line like in the example, by 2 points segments, where the reshaping to plot by segments is done reshaping the array with the same code as the example.

```
def waterfall_plot(fig,ax,X,Y,Z):
    '''
    Make a waterfall plot
    Input:
        fig,ax : matplotlib figure and axes to populate
        Z : n,m numpy array. Must be a 2d array even if only one line should be plotted
        X,Y : n,m array
    '''
    # Set normalization to the same values for all plots
    norm = plt.Normalize(Z.min().min(), Z.max().max())
    # Check sizes to loop always over the smallest dimension
    n,m = Z.shape
    if n>m:
        X=X.T; Y=Y.T; Z=Z.T
        m,n = n,m

    for j in range(n):
        # reshape the X,Z into pairs 
        points = np.array([X[j,:], Z[j,:]]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
        segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)        
        lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap='plasma', norm=norm)
        # Set the values used for colormapping
        lc.set_array((Z[j,1:]+Z[j,:-1])/2)
        lc.set_linewidth(2) # set linewidth a little larger to see properly the colormap variation
        line = ax.add_collection3d(lc,zs=(Y[j,1:]+Y[j,:-1])/2, zdir='y') # add line to axes

    fig.colorbar(lc) # add colorbar, as the normalization is the same for all, it doesent matter which of the lc objects we use
```

Therefore, plots looking like matlab waterfall can be easily generated with the same input matrixes as a matplotlib surface plot:

```
import numpy as np; import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Generate data
x = np.linspace(-2,2, 500)
y = np.linspace(-2,2, 40)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = np.sin(X**2+Y**2)
# Generate waterfall plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
waterfall_plot(fig,ax,X,Y,Z) 
ax.set_xlabel('X') ; ax.set_xlim3d(-2,2)
ax.set_ylabel('Y') ; ax.set_ylim3d(-2,2)
ax.set_zlabel('Z') ; ax.set_zlim3d(-1,1)
```

[image: Waterfall plot]

The function assumes that when generating the meshgrid, the `x` array is the longest, and by default the lines have fixed y, and its the x coordinate what varies. However, if the size of the y dimension is larger, the matrixes are transposed, generating the lines with fixed x. Thus, generating the meshgrid with the sizes inverted (`len(x)=40` and `len(y)=500`) yields:

[image: Non default waterfall plot]

Answer (score 3):

with a pandas dataframe with the x axis as the first column and each spectra as another column

```
offset=0
for c in s.columns[1:]:
    plt.plot(s.wavelength,s[c]+offset)
    offset+=.25
    plt.xlim([1325,1375])
```

[image]

Comment: Simple and sweet